# Implement a near real-time CPU capability like glAlphaFunc(GL_GREATER) with RGB source and RGBA overlay

Tags: c++, opengl, assembly, sse, rgba

Latency is the biggest concern here.  I have found that trying to render 3 1920x1080 video feeds with RGBA overlays to individual windows via OpenGL has limits.  I am able to render two windows with overlays or 3 windows without overlays just fine, but when the third window is introduced, rendering stalls are obvious.  I believe that the issue is due to the overuse of glAlphaFunc() to overlay and RGBA based texture on an RGB video texture.  In order to reduce the overuse, my thought is to move some of the overlay function into CPU (as I have lots of CPU - dual hexcore Xeon).  The ideal place to do this would be when copying the source RGB image to the mapped PBO and replacing the RGB values with the ones from the RGBA overlay where A > 0.

I have tried using Intel IPP methods, but there is no method available that doesn't involve multiple calls and results in too much latency.  I've tried straight C code, but this takes longer than the 33 ms that I am allowed.  I need help with creating an optimized assembly or SSE based routine that will provide minimal latency.

Compile the below code with > g++ -fopenmp -O2 -mtune=native

Basic C function for clarity:

```
void copyAndOverlay(const uint8_t* aSourceRGB, const uint8_t* aOverlayRGBA, uint8_t* aDestinationRGB, int aWidth, int aHeight) {
    int i;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<aWidth*aHeight; ++i) {
        if (0 == aOverlayRGBA[i*4+3]) {
           aDestinationRGB[i*3] = aSourceRGB[i*3]; // R
           aDestinationRGB[i*3+1] = aSourceRGB[i*3+1]; // G
           aDestinationRGB[i*3+2] = aSourceRGB[i*3+2]; // B
        } else {
           aDestinationRGB[i*3] = aOverlayRGBA[i*4]; // R
           aDestinationRGB[i*3+1] = aOverlayRGBA[i*4+1]; // G
           aDestinationRGB[i*3+2] = aOverlayRGBA[i*4+2]; // B
        }
    }
}

uint64_t getTime() {
  struct timeval tNow;
  gettimeofday(&tNow, NULL);
  return (uint64_t)tNow.tv_sec * 1000000 + (uint64_t)tNow.tv_usec;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int pixels = _WIDTH_ * _HEIGHT_ * 3;
  uint8_t *rgba = new uint8_t[_WIDTH_ * _HEIGHT_ * 4];
  uint8_t *src = new uint8_t[pixels];
  uint8_t *dst = new uint8_t[pixels];

  uint64_t tStart = getTime();

  for (int t=0; t<1000; ++t) {
    copyAndOverlay(src, rgba, dst, _WIDTH_, _HEIGHT_);
  }

  printf("delta: %lu\n", (getTime() - tStart) / 1000);

  delete [] rgba;
  delete [] src;
  delete [] dst; 

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If will help if you post the C code that you want to optimize

Comment: And some test framework :)

Comment: if you can guarantee that the function arguments can't alias, you might get faster code in C by using the `restrict` qualifier.

Comment: Something strange there, that code runs in under 3ms on my 4.4GHz FX-8350. The sse version I quickly hacked together runs under 1ms.

Comment: Wow, what a difference -O2 makes... on a AMD Phenom(tm) II X6 1075T Processor, I am getting ~ 5 ms (though I think this is lower due to cache) - At some point I turned off compiler optimization.  Without, it is ~ 30 ms

Comment: You could also divide up the images into stripes so you keep all your cores busy, unless the overhead is too big or you are hitting memory bandwidth limit anyway.

Comment: Looks like it's worth it, using `-fopenmp` and `#pragma omp parallel for` it improved to 0.7ms with 8 threads.

Comment: @Jester - Thanks for showing me my simple mistake and introducing me to OMP.  I feel like I have a new shiny toy!

Comment: Don't use `gettimeofday (...)` for performance counting. If the computer happens to re-synch its time with an NTP server in the middle of your algorithm, your results will be invalid. You want to use a monotonic clock, POSIX provides this through `clock_gettime (...)`.

Comment: Since he's using OpenMP now then he should use `omp_get_wtime()` for timing.

Comment: @user2751789, for SSE this would be a lot easier if the source and destination were RGBA instead of RGB.  Is that possible?

Comment: @Jester, can you post the SSE code you quickly hacked together?

Comment: @Zboson my code is pretty similar to what Apriori gave as answer, except I have not used `pblendvb`.

Comment: @Z boson, no RGBA is not really possible, it would require another conversion.

Comment: @Jester, btw I had a version before this that did not use blendv. But it used unaligned loads/stores, and over read and over wrote 4 bytes for the 24-bit color formats. But then I just updated the pointers by 12 bytes anyway. I'd guess that's what you did too, it was slower than the version I posted but still I think 2x faster than the original without OpenMP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an SSE4 implementation that is a little more than 5 times faster than the code you posted with the question (without parallelization of the loop). As written it only works on RGBA buffers that are 16-byte aligned and sized in multiples of 64, and on RGB buffers that are 16-byte aligned and sized in multiples of 48. The size will requirments will jive perfectly with your 1920x1080 resolution, and you may need to add code to ensure your buffers are 16-byte aligned.

```
void copyAndOverlay(const uint8_t* aSourceRGB, const uint8_t* aOverlayRGBA, uint8_t* aDestinationRGB, int aWidth, int aHeight) {
  __m128i const ocmp     = _mm_setzero_si128();
  __m128i const omskshf1 = _mm_set_epi32(0x00000000, 0x0F0F0F0B, 0x0B0B0707, 0x07030303);
  __m128i const omskshf2 = _mm_set_epi32(0x07030303, 0x00000000, 0x0F0F0F0B, 0x0B0B0707);
  __m128i const omskshf3 = _mm_set_epi32(0x0B0B0707, 0x07030303, 0x00000000, 0x0F0F0F0B);
  __m128i const omskshf4 = _mm_set_epi32(0x0F0F0F0B, 0x0B0B0707, 0x07030303, 0x00000000);
  __m128i const ovalshf1 = _mm_set_epi32(0x00000000, 0x0E0D0C0A, 0x09080605, 0x04020100);
  __m128i const ovalshf2 = _mm_set_epi32(0x04020100, 0x00000000, 0x0E0D0C0A, 0x09080605);
  __m128i const ovalshf3 = _mm_set_epi32(0x09080605, 0x04020100, 0x00000000, 0x0E0D0C0A);
  __m128i const ovalshf4 = _mm_set_epi32(0x0E0D0C0A, 0x09080605, 0x04020100, 0x00000000);
  __m128i const blndmsk1 = _mm_set_epi32(0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000);
  __m128i const blndmsk2 = _mm_set_epi32(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000, 0x00000000);
  __m128i const blndmsk3 = _mm_set_epi32(0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0x00000000);
  __m128i       a, b, c, x, y, z, w, p, q, r, s;
  uint8_t const *const aSourceRGBPast = aSourceRGB + 3 * aWidth * aHeight;

  while (aSourceRGB != aSourceRGBPast) {
    // source:
    //  aaabbbcccdddeeef
    //  ffggghhhiiijjjkk
    //  klllmmmnnnoooppp
    //
    // overlay:
    //  aaaabbbbccccdddd
    //  eeeeffffgggghhhh
    //  iiiijjjjkkkkllll
    //  mmmmnnnnoooopppp

    // load source
    a = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aSourceRGB       ));
    b = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aSourceRGB   + 16));
    c = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aSourceRGB   + 32));

    // load overlay
    x = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aOverlayRGBA     ));
    y = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aOverlayRGBA + 16));
    z = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aOverlayRGBA + 32));
    w = _mm_load_si128((__m128i const*)(aOverlayRGBA + 48));

    // compute blend mask, put 0xFF in bytes equal to zero
    p = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(x, ocmp);
    q = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(y, ocmp);
    r = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(z, ocmp);
    s = _mm_cmpeq_epi8(w, ocmp);

    // align overlay to be condensed to 3-byte color
    x = _mm_shuffle_epi8(x, ovalshf1);
    y = _mm_shuffle_epi8(y, ovalshf2);
    z = _mm_shuffle_epi8(z, ovalshf3);
    w = _mm_shuffle_epi8(w, ovalshf4);

    // condense overlay to 3-btye color
    x = _mm_blendv_epi8(x, y, blndmsk1);
    y = _mm_blendv_epi8(y, z, blndmsk2);
    z = _mm_blendv_epi8(z, w, blndmsk3);

    // align blend mask to be condensed to 3-byte color
    p = _mm_shuffle_epi8(p, omskshf1);
    q = _mm_shuffle_epi8(q, omskshf2);
    r = _mm_shuffle_epi8(r, omskshf3);
    s = _mm_shuffle_epi8(s, omskshf4);

    // condense blend mask to 3-btye color
    p = _mm_blendv_epi8(p, q, blndmsk1);
    q = _mm_blendv_epi8(q, r, blndmsk2);
    r = _mm_blendv_epi8(r, s, blndmsk3);

    // select from overlay and source based on blend mask
    x = _mm_blendv_epi8(x, a, p);
    y = _mm_blendv_epi8(y, b, q);
    z = _mm_blendv_epi8(z, c, r);

    // write colors to destination
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(aDestinationRGB     ), x);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(aDestinationRGB + 16), y);
    _mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(aDestinationRGB + 32), z);

    // update poniters
    aSourceRGB      += 48;
    aOverlayRGBA    += 64;
    aDestinationRGB += 48;
  }
}
```